# Understanding Angular production chunks

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, hash, angular-cli

I'm trying to understand how Angular builds prod chunks.
My prod-build produces the following files:

- main.hash.js
- polyfills.hash.js
- runtime.hash.js
- scripts.hash.js
- xxx-xxx-module-ngfactory.hash.js
- yyy-yyy-module-ngfactory.hash.js
- default~xxx-xxx-module-ngfactory~yyy-yyy-module-ngfactory.hash.js

I know what the first 4 are, but I'm confused about the rest.

1. xxx and yyy are lazy modules in my app, why does angular produce
   another file for them (default~...js)? what is it for?
2. Is it possible that to replace yyy-yyy-module-ngfactory.hash.js file
   with another version of the module from a difference build (with a
   different hash of course, hash987 for example)?

**I tried to do it:** I built the app (version 2) and replaced the yyy module file with an older one, and then replaced the referenced hash number in runtime.hash.js but it failed downloading the old chunk.
**Could you explain why and if its possible?**

Comment: Building modules individually is what makes lazy loading possible. If they were all compiled into 1 file it wouldn't be possible to inject different script files dependant on your site location.

Comment: @JonasPraem, I understand. But I'm asking about the content of each module chunk file and if its possible to replace one of them with an older chunk

Comment: Well a short answer to that is it contains the compiled code of the module. It contains references to all the components/templates/ids etc that the module needs to run. The reason you probably can't just replace with an old compiled is probably because it contains references to other hashed modules/elements - and these hashes are different each build. 

Can I ask why you wan't to do such a replace? might be key to answering your question properly

Comment: @JonasPraem, it's a business req. I need to update multiple modules for clients except some chosen modules. Is it possible? is there a workaround or a hack to do that?

Comment: Well what's the reason for not just making changes to the source code and recompiling?